# How to query an object from an array using Firestore and Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to query an object from Firestore, the  `uid` so I can return the following object as a value.

I have tried to make a function to be able to get the object 'Banana'

```
getFruit(fruitUid: string, basketUid: string): Promise<any> {
    const basketRef = this.afs.doc(`basket/${basketUid}`).ref;

    return this.afs.firestore.runTransaction((ts) => {
      return ts.get(basketUid).then((sfDoc) => {
        return sfDoc.data().fruits
        .filter(fruit => fruit.uid === fruitUid);
      });
    });
  }
```

Now I'm getting the following error: `FirebaseError: Every document read in a transaction must also be written.`

This is what the database looks like:

```
fruits: [
  {
    uid: '123ABC',
    name: 'Banana'
  },
  {
    uid: 'ABC123',
    name: 'Apple'
]
createdAt: 2019-04-20
```

Is there a way to get that specific object by specifing the `uid` so I can return a specific `fruit` from the array `fruits`?

Answer (score 0):

For a single document retrieval, you shouldn't need a transaction:

```
getFruit(fruitUid: string, basketUid: string): Promise<any> {
    const basketRef = this.afs.doc(`basket/${basketUid}`);

    return basketRef.get().then((sfDoc) => {
      return sfDoc.data().fruits
      .filter(fruit => fruit.uid === fruitUid);
    });
}
```